# Netbeans stop responding sometimes

Tags: java, netbeans

My Project has a large piece of code. Totally 5000-6000 lines now and has 100+ methods and 400+ components.

Sometimes working really hard in Netbeans because CPU goes %99 even small changes in codes.

I just paste 3 methods to my project has totally 100+ lines and Netbeans stop responding now. CPU always at %99 about 10-15 minutes.

Anyways disable Netbeans automatic checking whole codes when doing changes? Or any other idea why Netbeans stop responding?

```
Netbeans Version: 7.4
JDK Version: 64 Bit jdk1.7.0_45
CPU: Intel Core I7 950 3.07Ghz
RAM: 12GB RaM (DDR3 1066 MHz)
OS: Win7 Ultimate 64Bit
```

Regards.

Comment: NetBeans freezes on a core i7 system ? wow

Comment: re-factor your code so that it is not a monolith.  I am really hoping it is all in separate classes.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch I just edit my question and add all of components of my desktop.

Comment: @user2310289 All codes in same class. Because i must control all of components before program launch an for some other reasons.

Comment: @user2310289 How did you deduce that?!

Comment: @Elliott Frisch question edited again :)

Comment: Someones press downgrade button instead help here. How sad.

Comment: re-factor your code so that you don't have several thousand lines of code in one class. That is not how you write Java code, which you have not posted one line of. Regardless, your computer is ridiculously overpowered and your netbeans is slow because you have not designed your *code*.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Usually if I describe my code I may mention how many classes or Entity Beans, but certainly not how many methods.

Comment: @user2310289 Thanks for suggestion. I seperate whole codes to threads. Now netbeans looks stable. But still i must learn more stuff about threads. If you write as answer i can up it.

Comment: Cheers, have done so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

re-factor your code so that it is not a monolith.

Separate your code so that it is in multiple classes.

Have a look at this [page](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/06/07/5-class-design-principles-solid-in-java/) and remember "One class should have one and only one responsibility"